# Image transforms on remote server are broken by `cpresources/transforms` url

Tags: image-transforms

My local image transforms successfully load in the FE but they do not load remotely.

This is the local url where images load successfully `/uploads/case-studies/deployment-image/_caseStudyDeploymentImage/image.jpg`

This is the remote url where images are broken `https://www.mysite.com/cpresources/transforms/8?x=IXLDGt3eW`

This has happened before but i can’t remember why or how i fixed. i have cleared asset indexes in CP Settings.

Comment: Lots of other potential duplicates, workarounds and solutions: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/search?q=cpresources+transforms

Answer (score 1):

1.) Did you check if you have GD extension or ImageMagick extension working on the remote system?

2.) Are you using Apache on your remote system? If yes, is mod_rewrite working? (because the second URL does not point to a real file but is rewritten instead)

3.) Maybe you are using Nginx on the remote system and therefor pretty urls are not working?